# Calculating the mode of filtered data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am a graduate student pursuing my masters in geology (aka I am not an Excel guru) and currently working on my thesis have run into a problem.

My thesis's main point is to communicate that there are large amounts of undiscovered hydrocarbons left in the onshore section of Louisiana. I am trying to quantify this by showing that the majority of oil fields in Louisiana were operated before 1980 (since 1980 technology has really taken off in the industry and a lot of new techniques are available that could help re-open some of these old fields).

I have an Excel workbook of approximately 1850 pages. Each page contains the well data for one field. Some fields have had thousands of wells drilled on them, while other have had only a few. One of the many pieces of data contained within theses sheets are the dates of well permits. I would like to calculate the mode year of these well permits to identify the years in which each oil field hit its "peak development".

I am currently employing a filter to eliminate a lot of unnecessary data and to try and make calculations/macro creation easier for myself. The permit date is located in Column  I. I used the Year function in Column Q to remove the day and month from the date so as to be able to calculate the mode year. However, Excel refuses to calculate the mode as it keeps trying to use the filtered information to calculate and thus returns an error. There is no subtotal function for mode and I cannot find a solution that works for my circumstances on the Internet.

A filtered sheet looks like this:

[image: Before Filtering]

For the solution, I need the formula to calculate the mode for the entire Q column as the range of permit data will vary by field.

[image: After Filtering]

Comment: You want the mode, but only for the filtered values?  In your example above, the result would be 1947?  Just clarifying...  What is the filter condition that helps to eliminate the "unnecessary" data?  I know it's beyond the scope of your project, but a database, even a simple one like SQLite or MS Access might make short work of this effort and be a little more scalable than Excel.

Comment: By the way, there apparently is a hack for a subtotal-type mode formula:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/371589-mode-subtotal.html

Comment: @Hambone  yes I would like the mode for the filtered values only and yes the mdoe is 1947 for the displayed field. I have attached what the data looks like before the filter. It essentially takes out headings, some production information, and a few other things

Comment: @Hambone I saw that hack, but honestly couldnt figure out how to apply it  to my instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, I think you need to change your formula from `=Year()` to include a conditional to see if the row is a "necessary" row or not.  Based on the latest screenshot you posted, I think the simplest solution might be to do something like this in your year (Q) column, where this is the formula in Q2:

```
=if(isnumber(H2),Year(I2),"")
```

This would result in blanks for any invalid row, and your mode function could simply be:

```
=MODE(Q:Q)
```

Which would know to ignore blanks.

Now, there is a greater than 0% chance my formula above is too simplistic and that your filtering criteria can't be replicated with a formula.  If you have to that, you can create a custom VBA function to tell if a row is hidden or not (a filtered row will have hidden = true) that would look something like this:

```
Function Hidden(CellValue As Range) As Boolean
    Hidden = Rows(CellValue.Row).Hidden
End Function
```

And the corresponding year function in Q2 would change to:

```
=IF(Hidden(A2),"",YEAR(B2))
```

And the same mode function would apply.  I tested it on a small spreadsheet.  Before filtering, the mode for this data is 2006:

[image]

If I filter out non-blanks in column C, to eliminate my known mode, the formula in E1 does change to the next mode, demonstrating that filtered values are ignored:

[image]